# Spring boot jar Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, executable-jar

i have created spring rest services using eclipse IDE. It works fine in eclipse when i run using Debug configurations however when I export it as a executable JAR and run using below command

```
java -jar cs.jar
```

it gives me below error:

```
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedde
d container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.Embed
dedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
```

why it's not working as a jar?

Comment: Please update your question with all the log output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if you have included servlet-api jar in your classpath, if yes, delete it.

If servlet-api is in classpath, it is included in WEB-INF/lib and then the error is thrown because servlet container has already servlet api jar.

Delete servlet-api dependency from maven or gradle if exits or if this dependency is adding by any other module then exclude servlet api dependency like below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId><groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId><some dependency></artifactId>
    <version><version></version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```